# What does ~<type> do?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

When writing code I have encountered my linter expressing the type of `~<type>` (where `<type>` is a type not `<type>` literary). An example of this is `self`.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        reveal_type(self) # reveals "~A"
```

I assume this means "`A` or a subclass of `A`"; however, I was unable to find any information about it online.

Also, you can't use this syntax in code:

```
a: ~A # raises an exception: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'type'
```

If `a` would have been revealed it would be `Unknown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find it in the Mypy documentation, but Pyright seems similar, and its [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/type-concepts.md#inferred-type-of-self-and-cls-parameters) says:

> Within the function, the type of self is printed with a tilde preceding the class name. This indicates that the type is a TypeVar bound to the class rather than the class itself.

So I think Mypy's use of `~Classname` is the same.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3997f3ce8ab15269fc800062f75411865dbc0d55/Lib/typing.py#L737-L744), TypeVars are printed (repr) with a leading "+" if they are covariant, "-" if contravariant, and "~" if invariant (neither covariant nor contravariant).